# Error in isoMDS(d): zero or negative distance between objects

Tags: r, multi-dimensional-scaling

I'm trying to do a nonmetric MDS (R version 3.3.3) using the `isoMDS` function in the `MASS` package and I get this error:

```
Error in isoMDS(d): zero or negative distance between objects 1 and 2
```

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
# LOAD LIBRARY
library(MASS)

# CREATE FAKE DATA
a <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)
b <- c(2, 2, 2, 2)
c <- c(3, 3, 4, 5)
d <- c(4, 4, 7, 9)
x <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)

x
  a b c d
1 1 2 3 4
2 1 2 3 4
3 1 2 4 7
4 1 2 5 9

# EUCLIDEAN DISTANCE BETWEEN ROWS 1, 2, 3 and 4
d <- dist(x)

d
         1        2        3
2 0.000000                  
3 3.162278 3.162278         
4 5.385165 5.385165 2.236068

# NMDS
fit <- isoMDS(d)

Error in isoMDS(d) : distance négative ou nulle entre les objets 1 et 2
```

I don't know if there's a way of getting around this issue or if I'm doing something wrong. I understand that objects 1 and 2 are identical and that that's probably why the distance is negative or equals to zero. I found out that my question was a "FAQ", but one of the only answers I found is this:

> Short answer: you cannot compare distances including NAs, so there is no 
>   way to find a monotone mapping of distances. If the data really are identical for two rows, you can easily drop one of 
>   them whilst doing MDS, and then assign the position found for one to the 
>   other.

So, my next questions are: how do you drop rows whilst doing MDS, and is there any other way to perform a NMDS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Marco, but I'm not sure I understand. In my example, I wanted to compute the distances between rows 1, 2, 3 and 4 (not columns A, B, C and D). I just edited my question, to make it more clear!

Comment: What is the intuiton behind calculating distance between rows using euclidean or any other formula. ? How does it help in dimension reduction.

Answer (score 0):

The `dist` function computes *the distances between the rows of a data matrix*.
Your `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` vectors are the columns of the `x` matrix, not the rows.
A simple solution is to transpose `x`:

```
library(MASS)

a <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)
b <- c(2, 2, 2, 2)
c <- c(3, 3, 4, 5)
d <- c(4, 4, 7, 9)
x <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)

# Calculate distance between the columns
d <- dist(t(x))

# NMDS
fit <- isoMDS(d)

# initial  value 0.000000 
# final  value 0.000000 
# converged

fit
# $points
#        [,1]       [,2]
# a -4.594429  0.4509513
# b -2.770312 -0.3638885
# c  1.098884 -0.3114594
# d  6.265857  0.2243966
# 
# $stress
# [1] 7.976932e-15
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Don't we change the question if you transpose the data?

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, you have identical rows.
You can omit identical rows when you first create the distance matrix

```
d <- dist(x[-1,])
```

Then continue as normal

```
fit <- isoMDS(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try the `vegan::metaMDS` function:

```
library(vegan)
#> This is vegan 2.5-3

x <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                b = c(2, 2, 2, 2), 
                c = c(3, 3, 4, 5), 
                d = c(4, 4, 7, 9))

# The warnings are expected for such a small dataset
fit <- vegan::metaMDS(comm = dist(x))
#> ... Procrustes: rmse 0.09543314  max resid 0.108719 
#> *** No convergence -- monoMDS stopping criteria:
#>     17: stress < smin
#>      3: scale factor of the gradient < sfgrmin
#> Warning in vegan::metaMDS(comm = dist(x)): stress is (nearly) zero: you may
#> have insufficient data

ordiplot(fit, type = "text")
```

[image]

Variables/columns "a" and "b" (1 and 2) get the same coordinates.

---

Similarly, using the `smacof::mds` function:

```
library(smacof)
fit2 <- smacof::mds(delta = dist(x), type = "ordinal")
fit2$conf
#>           D1           D2
#> 1  0.5742535  0.007220978 # 1 & 2 get the same coordinates
#> 2  0.5742535  0.007220978
#> 3 -0.2749314 -0.034928060
#> 4 -0.8735757  0.020486105
```